# Is it possible to use a class method to update a set that is one of it's attributes? (i.e. writes in itself)

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, data-persistence

Well, i believe an example will provide a better understanding:

```
class FileFormats():

    def __init__(self):

        self.a_set = {gif, jpg, png}


    def add_value(self, a_value):
        self.a_set.update(a_value)
```

I tested and it doesn't work (and i think it's fine that it doesn't work?)
I can't think of any other way to do something like that without using a '.txt' file and open(), read(), write() methods or some sort of database. But maybe there's another way 
i can get persistence and maybe some of you people could enlighten me?

I believe there's a very simple answer and probably i missed something on my python lessons, so, if you just tell me google this or that  i would be completely fine with that.

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the answer given of prepending `self` before attributes and methods, note that you cannot update a set with a value. You can only update a set with an iterable. The value must be within a list or tuple. The last line in your example should be changed to `self.a_set.update([a_value])`.

Comment: my mistake, i forgot to include self. in the example.

Comment: In what sense does it not work? `f = FileFormats(); f.add_value({'bmp', 'xcf'})` works fine...

Comment: I think i expressed myself badly, i mean, it works, but when you leave interactive mode the updated values will be gone...

Comment: Oh well I was working on a answer but it seems what you want has nothing to do with what you had asked. If you want persistence for a couple of values, the easiest is to use a file.

Comment: You can use `pickle` or `json` to read or write data to or from file, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: i wanted the module to write in itself so that a_set = {a} becomes a_set{a, b} after module.class.add_value((b))

Comment: Nevermind, i will just use other files to save the values. Thanks